# How to set custom capabilities for custom taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, capabilities

I am trying to set some custom capabilities for a custom taxonomy. I am trying the following:

```
'capabilities' => array(
    'manage_terms' => 'manage_'.$types,
    'edit_terms' => 'edit_'.$types,
    'delete_terms' => 'delete_'.$types,
    'assign_terms' => 'assign_'.$types
)
```

where `$types` is the plural form of the taxonomy slug. This is part of a larger function to programmatically create custom taxonomies.

---

I am viewing the capabilities using User Role Editor (and have looked in the `options` table of the DB) and these capabilities are not all created. I can see the caps for `edit_terms` and `delete_terms` but none for `manage_terms` and `assign_terms` which are the ones I actually need.

I am struggling to see what I am doing wrong so any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array that you pass on taxonomy creation should consist of existing capabilities, it doesn't create them. You'd have to do that manually with `add_cap()` before registering your taxonomy. Unless you need specific capabilities to vary with each of your new taxonomies it's best to pass existing capabilities like `manage_categories` or create one set of capabilities, eg `manage_custom_taxonomies` to cover all of them.

Comment: Thank you, got it working now! The docs are not clear on this and other answers I have seen online implied you could do what I was trying above.